# Why can I still see encrypted File and Attachment?

Tags: encryption, shield-encryption, shield

I have enabled Salesforce Shield in a developer org of mine, checked File and Attachment to make encrypted. After that, I created another user with a different profile who have not permission to see encrypted data. But Still that user able to see that file or attachments and also able to download.

then what is the benefit of Shield Encryption. If Every user of Org is able to see or even able to download that encrypted file & attachment.

**Please Clear me the exact benefit of Shield Encryption.**

**When i Encrypted any file and attachment using Shield then who will able to see and who will not. please explain to me with the needful example.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shield Platform Encryption encrypts your data *at rest*, on the Salesforce server. It helps you to meet compliance requirements for your industry. Salesforce Shield is not intended to protect your data against your users, who access it in the normal course of their duties. That's what the standard Salesforce security architecture (Record-Level Security/CRUD/FLS) is meant to achieve.

The permission "View Encrypted Data" applies only to [Classic Encryption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm), which can be enabled only on short text fields and includes a number of other restrictions. It's a completely different product from Salesforce Shield and has different use cases.

"View Encrypted Data" has no effect on Salesforce Shield. With the latter product enabled, users can continue to see all data to which they are entitled under your established security model.